# Add to y error bar and error ellipse.Help me please

Tags: errors, pstricks, pst-plot, pstricks-add, bar

```
'''
\savedata{\myData}[       
0.49328505454e+003  4.49778525251e+003    
0.49584934756e+003  4.49579821639e+003    
0.49334314462e+003  4.49720809875e+003    
0.49389975903e+003  4.49785443271e+003
]
\psset{llx=-1cm,urx=5cm,lly=-1cm,ury=5cm}
\pstScalePoints(1,1){492 sub}{4494 sub}
\begin{psgraph}[
   axesstyle=frame,
   mathLabel=false,labelFontSize=\small,
   Dy=0.5, Dx=0.5,
   Oy=4494, Ox=492,
   xticksize=0 5, yticksize=0 5](0,0)(5.001,5.001){10cm}{10cm}
   \listplot[plotstyle=dots,showpoints,
             dotstyle=triangle*,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{\myData}               
    \listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.8pt,
    showpoints=false]{\myData}                     
\end{psgraph}
'''
```

I want to add y error bars and error ellipse according to my data.

Comment: Please submit your MWE (Minimal Working Example). It must be as minimal as possible with `\documentclass{...}...\begin{document}...\end{document}` so we can reproduce your problem quicker.

Comment: You need the additional values for the error bars! See https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples#dotError

Comment: Yes.But how can i do?Random values.